# UI Layout for registration forms in Android Tablet

Tags: android, forms, user-interface, tablet

I am developing an application for android 3.0 tablets. One activity of this application contains user registration form.

This is my preliminary xml layout with few fields

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/lable"
            android:text="Name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstName"
                style="@style/editText"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastName"
                style="@style/editText"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- USER NAME -->

        <TextView
            style="@style/lable"
            android:text="Choose your username" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            style="@style/editText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Following is corresponding style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="lable">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="editText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>

        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

After adding few fields i noticed there is lot of empty space on the screen. Can anyone tell me what would be proper arrangement in tablet ui for creating registration form?

Comment: It's not a kind of question you'd ask on SO, I think. Because it's a design or ux question, not a programming one. Maybe try on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, it's not a ux.stackexchange question because it's asking for technical advice. It has been asked there already and closed off. Questions should only be posted on one site, if it belongs elsewhere the the moderators will migrate it so it's not duplicated across the SE network.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting the first name and last name fields side by side to take up more space horizontally as tablets are wider than they are tall.

Name: *First Name   Last Name*
                    or maybe
Name:  *Last Name, First Name*

You might also try using fragments to display the activity before or after the registration form activity if possible.